# Local notifications schedule for 3 months, 6 moths from now using ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I'm developing reminder app using ionic and cordova.

For local notification I've used [cordova-plugin-local-notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). 
By default this plugin has only day, month, year or week interval. I want to customize the schedule time, specifying for example the time, 3 months, 6 months, 2 year or 5 year.

Please try to find out the solution for me.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the [project wiki](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling), you can delay the local notification using this code:

```
var now             = new Date().getTime(),
_3_months_from_now = new Date(now + 3*30*24*60*60*1000),
_6_months_from_now = new Date(now + 2*_3_months_from_now),
_2_year_from_now = new Date(now + 4*_6_months_from_now),
_5_year_from_now = new Date(now + 10*_6_months_from_now),
_5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5*1000);

cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    text: "Delayed Notification",
    at: _3_months_from_now,
    led: "FF0000",
    sound: null
});
```

I suggest you to use a dedicated js library to manipulate dates, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). This will help you to avoid many headache and the code will be more clear.

Comment: Thank you my friend.. it works for me.. one more question.. how to specify time?

Comment: And how to repeat the action?

Comment: I could use an html  `<input type="date"/>` to select the date, then add a button that on every click, grab the selected date and schedule the notification at that date. But this off topic here (this isn't related to cordova/ionic): if you need more help on this, ask a dedicated question. Thank you.

Comment: @lifeisfoo can i use a moment.js date in the attribute 'at'?

Comment: @jedi yes, just extract the plain js Date object from the moment object using `yourMomentObj.toDate()`. See [the documentation for more information](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/)