# ngCordova LocalNotification plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework

I'm using the ngCordova LocalNotification plugin in my Ionic app and I am trying to get it to repeat but with a random time span.

For example the user will trigger the notification to launch in 1 minute, and after that I would need to have the notification launched again in another 2 minutes (hypothetical example, in real life scenario the time span would be much higher, ie a couple days).

So far I can get the notification to execute for the first time.

Then, I am using the $cordovaLocalNotification:trigger method to detect when the notification was triggered and inside of that method I have a code to schedule a new notification.

All of this works, but in order to launch whatever it is inside of that method's body, I have to acknowledge the notification on my device and click on it, then it launches this method.

So I am wondering if there's a way to have it schedule a new notification without me having to open the previous notification?

All of this has to happen locally on the device and the notification should persist even if the device is rebooted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349958/local-notifications-schedule-for-3-months-6-moths-from-now-using-ionic) helpful?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, no :( I don't have any problem with dates, my pain is that in order to schedule the new notification, I have to click on the delivered notification and then that code inside of my method executes. However, in real life scenario we can't expect the users to click on every notification they receive, many times they will simply just ignore it or delete it. So I guess the new notification would have to be scheduled somehow in the background without them ever opening the app, and that is the approach that's desirable anyway. Any idea where to look for an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that the `trigger` event is generated only when you click on the notification? Docs says that: "_Listens on the '$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger' event, which is fired when local notification was triggered._".

Comment: Exactly! I have just an alert() inside of that event so I'd know when it was executed and the only time I see the alert is if I respond to that notification. I also put there a call to schedule new notification so I'd get 1 notification in 1 minute and then I expect to receive another one in another minute, but it simply won't happen unless I respond to the previous notification. After that, I get the notification in the 60 seconds as expected.

Comment: I am thinking, could it be something with me not using $rootScope? I have this on $scope in my controller that is attached to the abstract: true state in the app config.

Comment: You can see the alert only when the app is in foregroud, so it seems that it works only when you click on the notification (that open the app). You could check if the alert is working even if you don't click on the notification, opening the app after the notification is displayed (without clicking it). But I think that the problem here is the application in backround: I remember that, when the application go in backround, the webview stop the javascript execution.

Comment: OK I tested it now. Yes, the alert gets triggered if I open up the app without clicking the notification. Another thing, the notification does not get cleared from the panel after opening the app, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Note: in the alert I print the method parameters, and the state always says foreground (naturally as I opened up the app).

Comment: I write a real answer below, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application go in backround, the webview stops the javascript execution. When you click on the notification, the app became a foreground process and javascript continue the execution.

So it seems that it works only when you click on the notification (that open the app) because only when the app is opened, the js code is executed.

You could double check this if you don't click on the notification, opening the app after the notification is displayed (without clicking it).

To clear all the triggered notification you could use the `getTriggeredIds(scope)` method to get all triggered notification IDs and the `clear(ids, scope)` method to clear them.

See the [localNotification plugin documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) for more information.

Comment: thanks mate, so i should post a new question now asking specifically about this background/foreground problem?

Comment: If you are interested in the topic yes: this is a public place where you can ask everything that is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Search always in the site, before ask, if your problem has been resolved yet.

Comment: Well yes I need to figure this one out haha. Thanks a lot for your help so far!