# Scheduling local notifications from the background (Ionic + ngCordova)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework

I am using the ngCordova LocalNotification plugin in my Ionic app to schedule the notifications on the device and deliver them locally. My app requires to schedule a new notification every time the previous one is delivered.

I am using the $cordovaLocalNotification:trigger method to schedule another notification upon receiving the last one. Everything works fine as long as I respond to the received notification and click on it. If I simply clear or ignore the notification, no new notification is scheduled and subsequently delivered.

So far I managed to [figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550913/) that the problem is that the call is registered only when the app is brought to the foreground. So I am wondering how to execute my code when the app is in the background? Obviously, I cannot expect every user to reply to every notification in order to schedule the new one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you are going to reschedule the notification with a certain time once it's triggered, why don't you schedule multiple notifications to start with with different times?

Comment: i think it could work but I'll have to look at it closer. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There at least two different cordova plugins to do this:

- [Cordova background mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)
- [Cordova background app](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app)

The first allow you to execute code while the application is in background, while the second transform your app in a service.

Look at [this example](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#examples) of the first plugin to know how to execute code in background.

In your specific case, you should listen for the trigger event in the background code.